# Smart Contract Missing tokens

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, tokens

Hello Ethereum Guru's,

I am trying to replicate the first example outlined in 'Ethereum in practice part 1' (https://www.ethereum.org/token) using Ethereum Wallet on my Macbook.

I had 1.0 of Ether in the Main account (Etherbase) prior to starting.

Here's what I did:

*Contracts > Deploy New Contract >

*Copied and pasted the code from example.

*Used the Parameters:  MyToken, 10000, MySuperToken, %, 2

*Did not adjust the 'Select Fee' slider at the bottom of the page...just hit the 'Deploy Button'.

*After hitting Deploy it created a contract but gave me the following error:
 'No data is deployed on the contract address!'.

*Some place I read that I needed to send it more gas.  So I sent the 'new contract' some gas from my Main Etherbase account.

Here's what I'm seeing:

*In the blog 'https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/03/how-to-build-your-own-cryptocurrency/' it states that after creating the smart contract the following should occur:

"Click the account named “Etherbase” (your main account) and after no more than a minute you should see that your account will show that you have 100% of the shares you just created."

This is not the case for me.  I do not see anything other than:
(1) 'Latest Transactions' shows that the contract was created and that an additional amount of gas was sent from my Etherbase account.
(2) Main Etherbase account has been depleted by the amount of gas used for the above actions.

Where did my 10,000 tokens of "MySuperToken" go to?  What step did I mess up on?  Are there screenshots somewhere of how to create a custom token using this GUI?

Thanks for your help in advance!

~Boss429